# BulkInsert filepath in a variable sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have seen few post about using a variable name with a bulk insert but I cannot make it work.
I have to do 20 bulk inserts in the same scripts, the directory is the same but the filename changes.I cannot get the syntax right.

this is what I have done

```
        DECLARE @CsvFilePath varchar(255)
        DECLARE @SQL_BULK VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @CsvFilePath='C:\MyDirectory'

        IF object_id(N'MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE MyTable
        GO

        CREATE TABLE MyTable 
        (
            CustomerNo
        )
        SET @SQL_BULK='BULK INSERT MyTable FROM ''' + @CsvFilePath + '\MyFileName.txt' + '''
        WITH (FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR='~',ROWTERMINATOR='\n')'
        exec (@SQL_BULK)
        GO
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: print out the SQL that you generate, copy/paste and run it. What is the error message?

Comment: Your @SQL_BULK string looks to not have correct escaped sequence around Field terminator and row terminator. You're missing some '

Comment: I am getting must declare @CsvFilePath

Comment: Are you getting this when you create the SP, run the SP or run the copied out code? Post the code that you copied out?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen yes I missed the escape sequence